# want to change state in react js when at the end of quiz and display the info

Tags: reactjs

This is my function which changes  state when reached the end of quiz

```
finishQuiz = () => {
    if (this.state.currentQuestion === Quizdata.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        isEnd: true
      });
    }
  };
```

This is me using the isEnd in  the render i have called this function on the finish button at the very bottom so when i click the finish button it should make isEnd true and displaying the score as below.but nothing happens when the end is reached but logic looks right

```
render() {
    const { userAns, options, currentQuest, isEnd } = this.state;
    if (isEnd) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3 className="SummaryResults">
            Quiz Finished, You scored {this.state.scores}/{Quizdata.length - 1}!
          </h3>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="quizForm">
          <br></br>
          {/*  <Welcome stateQuiz1={this.changeToquiz2} />*/}

          <div>
            <ProgressBar animated now={this.state.currentQuest * 10} />
          </div>
          {this.state.questions}
          <br></br>
          <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Q{this.state.currentQuest}</p>
          {this.state.pictures}
          <br></br>

          {options.map(option => (
            <Button
              size="lg"
              block
              key={option.id}
              className={`ui floating message options
            ${userAns === option ? "selected" : null}
           `}
              onClick={() => this.checkAns(option)}
            >
              {option}
            </Button>
          ))}

          <br></br>
          <Button onClick={() => this.checkAns()}>
            CHECK <FaHorse />
          </Button>
          {currentQuest < Quizdata.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
              onClick={() => {
                this.nextQuestion();
                this.pushtoDB();
                this.finishQuiz();
              }}
            >
              NEXT <FaArrowRight />
            </Button>
          )}
          <br></br>

          {currentQuest === Quizdata.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                this.finishQuiz();
                this.pushtoDB2();

              }}
            >
              Finish
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Any help thanks

Comment: what happens if you remove ```if (this.state.currentQuestion === Quizdata.length - 1) {```? in finishQuiz

Comment: @JuniusL. but i want to make the state true only when i have reached the end of the quiz so i need that

Comment: Shoudln't be it  ```this.state.currentQuest``` instead of ```this.state.currentQuestion``` ??  as currentQuestion is probably undefined and skips that if statement

Comment: @crrmacarse u are correct i that was my fault thanks its working i was using wrong variables

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing this code is you can try like this. Also you can check your isEnd state, you can console whether it is changing or not.

```
render() {
    const { userAns, options, currentQuest, isEnd } = this.state;
      return (

        {isEnd && <div>
          <h3 className="SummaryResults">
            Quiz Finished, You scored {this.state.scores}/{Quizdata.length - 1}!
          </h3>
        </div>}

        {!isEnd && <div className="quizForm">
          <br></br>
          {/*  <Welcome stateQuiz1={this.changeToquiz2} />*/}

          <div>
            <ProgressBar animated now={this.state.currentQuest * 10} />
          </div>
          {this.state.questions}
          <br></br>
          <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Q{this.state.currentQuest}</p>
          {this.state.pictures}
          <br></br>

          {options.map(option => (
            <Button
              size="lg"
              block
              key={option.id}
              className={`ui floating message options
            ${userAns === option ? "selected" : null}
           `}
              onClick={() => this.checkAns(option)}
            >
              {option}
            </Button>
          ))}

          <br></br>
          <Button onClick={() => this.checkAns()}>
            CHECK <FaHorse />
          </Button>
          {currentQuest < Quizdata.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
              onClick={() => {
                this.nextQuestion();
                this.pushtoDB();
                this.finishQuiz();
              }}
            >
              NEXT <FaArrowRight />
            </Button>
          )}
          <br></br>

          {currentQuest === Quizdata.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                this.finishQuiz();
                this.pushtoDB2();

              }}
            >
              Finish
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>}
      );
    }
```

Comment: ```{isEnd && <div>``` to ```{isEnd && <React.Fragment>```